# Typewriter in VS2017 - TypeScript dependency loading with RequireJs uses Knockout?

Tags: c#, typescript, knockout.js, requirejs, typewriter

So currently am working on streamlining my front end development with TypeScript and typewriter plug-in for VS.

What I'm currently having issues with is handling my module loading in the browser using RequireJS. I have followed several tuts online and read through the documentations of each of the technologies used even read tons of SO material as well. I'm thinking this is like complex arithmetic where all the sudden it'll click and be a piece of cake but right now all the moving pieces have my mind in a state of spaghetti. I could really use some help here.

I'm going to use a complex class structure example because I believe the issue lies within missing imports and exports / namespace and module declarations however - I don't know for sure because I just can't wrap my head around everything going on here.. yet. I will do my best to provide comprehensive code details using actual app code and structure.

C# Class:

```cs
public class SnakeViewModel
{
    // Project
    public ProjectViewModel Project { get; set; }
    public long ProjectId { get; set; }

    // Workflow
    public Workflow Workflow { get; set; }
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public List<Workflow> Workflows { get; set; }

    // Workflow Phases
    public List<WorkflowPhase> WorkflowPhases { get; set; }

    //Contractors - Name and ID
    public List<ContractorDetails> ContractorDetails { get; set; }

    ...
    ......
}
```

TypeWriter Template:

```
${
using Typewriter.Extensions.Types;

Template(Settings settings)
{
    settings.IncludeAllProjects();                
    settings.OutputExtension = ".ts";
}

string KnockoutType(Property p) {
    if (p.Type.IsEnumerable) {
        return p.Type.Name.TrimEnd('[',']');
    }

    return p.Type;
}

string KnockoutValue(Property property) {
    var type = KnockoutType(property);

    if (IsEnumerableViewModel(property)) {
        return $"ko.observableArray<Knockout{type}>([])";
    } else if (property.Type.IsEnumerable) {
        return $"ko.observableArray<{type}>([])";
    }

    return $"ko.observable<{type}>()";
}    

bool IsEnumerableViewModel(Property p) {
    string type = KnockoutType(p);
    return p.Type.IsEnumerable && type.EndsWith("ViewModel");
}

}
namespace Sidewinder {

$Classes(RIOT.Mvc4.ViewModels.*)[ 

export interface $Name {
    $Properties[
    $name: $Type;]
}

export class Knockout$Name {        
    $Properties[
    public $name = $KnockoutValue;]

    constructor(model: $Name) {
        this.map(model);
    }

    public map(model: $Name) {
        $Properties(x => !IsEnumerableViewModel(x))[
        this.$name(model.$name);]
        $Properties(x => IsEnumerableViewModel(x))[
        this.$name(model.$name.map(this.map$Name));]
    }

    $Properties(x => IsEnumerableViewModel(x))[

    public map$Name(model: $KnockoutType) {
        return new Knockout$KnockoutType(model);
    }]

    public getModel() {
        return {
            $Properties(x => !IsEnumerableViewModel(x))[
            $name: this.$name(),]
            $Properties(x => IsEnumerableViewModel(x))[
            $name: this.$name().map(x => x.getModel())][,]
        }
    }
}]
}
```

TS Output:

```js
namespace Sidewinder {

export interface SnakeViewModel {

    project: ProjectViewModel;
    projectId: number;
    workflow: Workflow;
    entityName: string;
    workflows: Workflow[];
    workflowPhases: WorkflowPhase[];
    contractorDetails: ContractorDetails[];

    ...
    ......
}

export class KnockoutSnakeViewModel {        

    public project = ko.observable<ProjectViewModel>();
    public projectId = ko.observable<number>();
    public workflow = ko.observable<Workflow>();
    public entityName = ko.observable<string>();
    public workflows = ko.observableArray<Workflow>([]);
    public workflowPhases = ko.observableArray<WorkflowPhase>([]);
    public contractorDetails = ko.observableArray<ContractorDetails>([]);

    ...
    ......

    constructor(model: SnakeViewModel) {
        this.map(model);
    }

    public map(model: SnakeViewModel) {

        this.project(model.project);
        this.projectId(model.projectId);
        this.workflow(model.workflow);
        this.entityName(model.entityName);
        this.workflows(model.workflows);
        this.workflowPhases(model.workflowPhases);
        this.contractorDetails(model.contractorDetails);

        ...
        ......           
    }

    public getModel() {
        return {            
            project: this.project(),
            projectId: this.projectId(),
            workflow: this.workflow(),
            entityName: this.entityName(),
            workflows: this.workflows(),
            workflowPhases: this.workflowPhases(),
            contractorDetails: this.contractorDetails(),

            ...
            ......                
        }
    }
} 
}
```

Compiled JS:

```js
var Sidewinder;
(function (Sidewinder) {
var KnockoutSnakeViewModel = (function () {
    function KnockoutSnakeViewModel(model) {
        this.project = ko.observable();
        this.projectId = ko.observable();
        this.workflow = ko.observable();
        this.entityName = ko.observable();
        this.workflows = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.workflowPhases = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.contractorDetails = ko.observableArray([]);
        ...
        ......

        this.map(model);
    }
    KnockoutSnakeViewModel.prototype.map = function (model) {
        this.project(model.project);
        this.projectId(model.projectId);
        this.workflow(model.workflow);
        this.entityName(model.entityName);
        this.workflows(model.workflows);
        this.workflowPhases(model.workflowPhases);
        this.contractorDetails(model.contractorDetails);
        ...
        ......

    };
    KnockoutSnakeViewModel.prototype.getModel = function () {
        return {
            project: this.project(),
            projectId: this.projectId(),
            workflow: this.workflow(),
            entityName: this.entityName(),
            workflows: this.workflows(),
            workflowPhases: this.workflowPhases(),
            contractorDetails: this.contractorDetails(),
            ...
            ......
        };
    };
    return KnockoutSnakeViewModel;
}());
Sidewinder.KnockoutSnakeViewModel = KnockoutSnakeViewModel;  
})(Sidewinder || (Sidewinder = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=SnakeViewModel.js.map
```

Ok, so that shows all my compilations - next i'm going to show some screenshots of settings and current structure and then show RequireJS code.

[Screenshot of File Structure..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYWWl.png)

[Screenshot of TS Compiler Settings..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw0Sg.png)

So now require stuff - it's very rudimentary currently.

Config file:

```js
declare var require: any;
require.config({
baseUrl: "/Scripts"
});
```

Global Include:

```cs
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ScriptRequire")
<script src="~/Scripts/app/require-config.js"></script>
```

Snake.cshtml:

```cs
@section scripts{
<script>
    require(["App/views/project/snake"]);
</script>
}
```

Snake.ts:

```js
namespace Sidewinder {

export class ViewModel extends KnockoutSnakeViewModel {

    constructor(model: SnakeViewModel) {
        super(model);
    }

    getViewModel() {

    }
}

$(function () {
    let initModel = {
        projId: $("#projId").val(),
        wfId: $("#wfId").val()
    }
    $.post("/ProjectApi/ProjectSnakeView",
        initModel,
        data => {
            if (data != null) {
                console.log(data);
                var model = new ViewModel(data);
                ko.applyBindings(model);
            }
        });
});
}
```

Snake.js:

```js
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
var extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
    ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; 
}) ||
    function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; 
};
return function (d, b) {
    extendStatics(d, b);
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = 
b.prototype, new __());
};
})();
var Sidewinder;
(function (Sidewinder) {
var ViewModel = (function (_super) {
    __extends(ViewModel, _super);
    function ViewModel(model) {
        return _super.call(this, model) || this;
    }
    ViewModel.prototype.getViewModel = function () {
    };
    return ViewModel;
}(Sidewinder.KnockoutSnakeViewModel));
Sidewinder.ViewModel = ViewModel;
$(function () {
    var initModel = {
        projId: $("#projId").val(),
        wfId: $("#wfId").val()
    };
    $.post("/ProjectApi/ProjectSnakeView", initModel, function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            console.log(data);
            var model = new ViewModel(data);
            ko.applyBindings(model);
        }
    });
});
})(Sidewinder || (Sidewinder = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=snake.js.map
```

Alright.. so that should be all the code. The html itself is all KO bound and I'm simply trying to get it to wire up bindings and display returned data at the moment. I'm getting dependency errors obviously and I don't understand the namespace/module/ having to reference everything even though it builds without issues and the compiler doesn't complain.. ugh.

The only thing that RequireJS is injecting into the page is the Snake.Js file when it obviously should be injecting all required subclasses of the viewmodel itself.

This front-end stuff has gotten a bit complex these days.

I'm sure I've left stuff out and not followed a specific rule to a tee so please inform me of any specific issues with this post before raising a flag - more than willing to answer further questions and learn more.